# in line chart, line is going beyond height when I remove y axis

Tags: charts, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I am using react-chartjs-2 version 2.7.6. In line chart, if I keep y axis graph line is in limit.
[image]

I want to remove y axis but when I remove y axis graph line goes above starting point.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the chart's configuration, I would suggest to hide only the y-axis tick labels instead of the entire y-axis:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                display: false
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Another solution could be to add a `suggestedMax` property to the y-axis. Use `Math.max()` or any other function to get the maximum `y` value you're going to receive and then pass this value to `suggestedMax`:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: {
            suggestedMax: 5
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway if you could post your chart's configuration it would be helpful.